# assign into multiple variable in same line in python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook for Python and also using Numpy Lib.
Here is what i have tried

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10, 21)
print(arr)
slice_arr = arr[:5]= 6
print(slice_arr)
print(arr)
```

Output is :

```
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
6
[ 6  6  6  6  6 15 16 17 18 19]
```

But I thought **slice_arr** would be `[ 6  6  6  6  6]` as i am getting first 5 element from **arr** and assigning `6` to all 5 elements and then assigning to **slice_arr**

How this statements would executed and How **slice_arr** value is `6`?

Does `6` is assigned separately to arr[:5] and `slice_arr`?

If the assignment if from right to left then `slice_arr` should be `[ 6  6  6  6  6]`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple assignments like this are not common, and not encouraged (without good reason):

```
slice_arr = arr[:5]= 6
```

Assigning an immutable object like a number to several variables is fine:

```
In [215]: x = y = 10
```

Assigning a mutable object like an array or list should be done with caution:

```
In [216]: x = y = [1,2,3]
In [217]: x[0]=12
In [218]: y
Out[218]: [12, 2, 3]
```

The simple interpretation of [216] is that the same list is assigned to both variables.

While I haven't seen your expression before, it makes sense to me that `slice_arr` would be `6`, the value on the RHS.

The `arr[:5] = 6` is executed as `arr.__setitem(slice(None,5), 6)`, that is, a method call on `arr`.

Conceivably the interpreter could also execute  `slice_arr = arr.__getitem__(slice(None,5))`, but it would be simpler (and less ambiguous) if it is executed `slice_arr = 6`.  That is, assign the same thing to both objects, rather than chain the action.

Another way to look at this, is that the replication of `6` is done within `arr`, or as part of the process of mutating `arr`.  It isn't replicated before the assignment.  `numpy` operates within Python.  The Python interpreter parses the code, translating it into function and method calls.

---

Here's a list example

```
In [235]: x=[1,2,3]
In [236]: y = x[1:] = [3,4,5]
In [237]: y
Out[237]: [3, 4, 5]
In [238]: x
Out[238]: [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

The documentation says the `target` assignments are done left to right.  I think this illustrates that:

```
In [43]: alist = alist[2:] = [1,2,3]
In [44]: alist
Out[44]: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

`alist` first gets the value `[1,2,3]`, and then a slice (the last element) is replaced by the same list.

A somewhat artificial array example of the left to right assignment:

```
In [45]: arr = np.arange(10)
In [46]: idx = arr[:idx] = 6
In [47]: idx
Out[47]: 6
In [48]: arr
Out[48]: array([6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [49]: idx = arr[:idx] = 4
In [50]: arr
Out[50]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`idx` is assigned the value before being used in the `arr[:idx]` expression.  This only works because the assignments are executed left to right (after the RHS has been evaluated).

From the `assignment` docs, the formal language expression is:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

> assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (starred_expression | yield_expression)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So here the right most value `6` is assigned separately to `arr[:5]` and `slice_arr`, am i right @hpaulj ?

Comment: @AbuYousuf, right.  the `expression list` (in @Gavin's reference) is evaluated once, and the assignment to `targets` is done individually.  I added an example showing that the `target` assignment occurs left to right (in your case `slice_arr` is assigned 6 first).

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

To get what you want, maybe do this:

slice_arr = arr[:5] = np.zeros([5])+6

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the `left to right` was a formal part of the syntax.  It makes sense, though in most cases it shouldn't make a difference.